# Single array with packed data vs multiple arrays

Tags: java, arrays, performance, memory

I need to decide which of these two approaches is better:

```
int[] packedData = new int[size];
```

vs:

```
short[] heightmap = new short[size];
byte[] tilesType = new byte[size];
byte[] tilesData = new byte[size];
```

The obvious advantage of second method over the first one is no need to use lots of bit shift operations in order to get/set the data and less boilerplate code, but how it looks like when it comes to performance and memory management? If both of these approaches have pros and cons, what are the recommended uses for them?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case?  Why not just make a data type that contains a short and two bytes, and make a `List` of them?

Comment: These arrays will be very large (milions or even more entries), so objects are out. I am working on terrain generator right now. Size of arrays is known, being power of two between 10 and 15 (depending on user input) squared.

Comment: I would only ever switch to #1 after having tried #2 and come to the conclusion that it was too slow.  Yes, there will be a minor performance tradeoff in exchange for the major readability tradeoff.

Comment: Hmm... I think I will test 2nd approach then and switch to 1st if it will be too slow, thanks for all comments.